# Separation of Concerns in MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm

I am working on understanding MVVM better, and from trusty Wikipedia (and lots of other research), I have gathered that the ViewModel holds presentation logic and the Model holds the business logic.

[MVVM Pattern (Image courtersy of Wikipedia)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSnki.png)

My question is, how is there a separation of concerns between logic and data when the Model is holding the business logic? Why is this a good pattern and why would I want to use it instead of using MVC where the Controller handles business and presentation logic (if I understand it correctly)? (I am using WPF, which based on my research, mainly uses MVVM and rarely uses MVC, and I still don't understand why).

Comment: Don't confuse _Model_ in those design patterns with data models. _Model_ is an application component. Per design pattern definition, the _Model_ contains the business logic of your application which includes data and the logic/rules to operate on this data. You want to decouple this application logic from the GUI/_View_ with the goal that changes to the _View_ will have no impact on your application. You want to be able to test the application without the GUI and a user.

Comment: MVVM strives to push  the lose coupling of MVC a few steps further: where in MVC the Model is directly coupled to the View, in MVVM the Model is completly unaware of the View and vice versa. Also the interaction between the GUI/View and the View Model is uni-directional thanks to technologies like data binding. The idea of all those patterns is the same: when developing an application the GUI will change frequently while the business logic remains the same. Additionally you have to write tests to ensure the integrity of the application.

Comment: To understand the benefit of any pattern, you must first understand the original propblem those patterns try to solve. Developing an application without any architectural structure, you will very likeley end up mixing GUI code and application code. The problem: when the GUI is mixed with the business logic you can't change the GUI without changing the application code. And you can't test your application code without the GUI (and a user that operates the GUI).

Comment: Patterns like MVC and MVVM are solving this problem by providing a template or a pattern that describes how to design your application so that application logic and GUI are separated, so that you can develop and test both independently. That's the goal of design patterns like MV and MVVM. **The goal is not to separate business logic and data** - this is totally irrelevant on the abstraction level that those patterns are working on.

Comment: The design of an application is like a top-down approach: once you have structured your application into independent MVVM components (Model, View Model and View), you can move one step down and start to design those individual components. For example to design the _Model_ with your valid goal to separate logic and data you can apply other architectural patterns, like introducing layers e.g., Data Layer and Business Layer and interfaces - but it's important to understand that' this is a different architectural abstraction level than the level that MVC and MVVM target.

Comment: The internet is full of examples and articles (apparently many are wrong). There are ebooks or paper books out there. Videos. If all these sources are not able to teach you the idea of MVC and MVVM then I highly doubt you will find a satisfying answer her on SO.

Comment: "Don't confuse Model in those design patterns with data models. Model is an application component. Per design pattern definition, the Model contains the business logic of your application which includes data and the logic/rules to operate on this data." This part made it really click for me, I got my satisfying answer on SO. Thanks ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Separating presentation logic from business logic allows you to change business logic without directly affecting presentation logic.

For example, if you have a RESTful web API that retrieves some data a view should render, the ViewModel should not be directly handling the HTTP operation or any translation of the incoming data. The ViewModel should ask a (separated) service class to retrieve that data and then the ViewModel can choose how to present that data, such as by pagination, sorting, filtering, and so on. You may choose to paginate at the web API level instead, but that's an implementation detail. In the event that your API contract changes, you can change the web API service without affecting the presentation logic: separation of concerns.

Comment: A service class is a good point, thank you for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

Let's get some things straight:

MVC = Model View Controller

MVVM = Model View ViewModel

With MVC, the controller controls the data and the business logic, the model stores the data temporarily, and the View can read the data from the model. In this model, the View handles the presentation logic. In C#, you can use Razor Pages (.cshtml) to dynamically insert values into the view.

MVVM is very similar. The Model is responsible for holding the data and business logic, the View Model holds the data temporarily, and the View controls the presentation logic. The main difference is the physical separation in your code.

With MVC, each step is separated into its own file. With MVVM, usually two or more steps are combined together into one file. This can be advantageous because it keeps you from having controllers that are hundreds or thousands of lines long if you have lots of pages. I personally still like MVC, because it keeps everything separate instead of combining it together.

Comment: That is helpful thank you!

Comment: _"The main difference is the physical separation in your code."_. Not true. Design patterns are always abstract not physical. Design patters like MVC and MVVM  are trying to separate the GUI from the application. Splitting your code into classes or having a one-type-per-file policy has nothing to do with those patterns. Neither MVC nor MVVM care about the length of your code files. They don't even care about the language you chose. You can view MVVM as an improved and modernized version of MVP which is an improved and modernized version of MVC. MVVM is far superior to MVC.